# Validar textbox com data

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Tenho um campo textbox que preciso digitar a data, gostaria de saber como posso fazer pra quando o usuário for digitando, fazer a validação do campo, e caso o mesmo não esteja correto, informe para o usuário. Qual a melhor forma de se fazer está validação? E como fazer?

Comment: Não conheço asp, mas enquanto pesquisava sobre datas, [encontrei isso.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939802/date-validation-with-asp-net-validator), Não tem nada a ver com o que eu fazia, mas lendo os comentários consegui resolver meu problema. Talvez possa te ajudar.

Comment: Ele funciona, só que ele aparece como Label, você sabe se tem como ele aparecer com ícone ? Obrigado.

Comment: Tem o jquery.maskedInput que faz máscara nos campos. Tu pode definir como: 99/99/9999 e ele só permitirá números e apenas nesse formato. https://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/ E tem outros plugins que fazem isso também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um jeito bem simples de você fazer esta validação é com o JQuery Mask.

Baixe o plugin aqui https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ e no seu código você vai fazer o seguinte:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtData" data-mask="00/00/0000" />
```

Não se esqueça de inicializar o plugin.

Você ainda pode criar uma classe com sua mascara e usar em outras partes do sistema, desta forma:

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          $(".data").mask("00/00/0000", {placeholder: "__/__/____"});
      })
</script>
```

Você pode usar o placeholder, como declarado acima para determinar no textbox como o valor digitado será inserido no campo.